# Problem with MySQL LEAST() function not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I've been recently using LEAST(tb1, tb2, tb3) AS name within my queries to fetch minimal values across multiple columns and check whether they were not equal to a default value of 0.00

So far it was working correctly and as intended for me, as well, the version of the script on a remote server is working fine.

However, after changing column defaults and NULL status (I was attempting to see if i could use NULL as opposed to 0.00, which after reading the LEAST documentation would not have been what I wanted to do.) and then afterwards re-importing the table I was originally using. It still will not work as it did before, for no apparent reason, my queries that use LEAST() return nothing at all, empty arrays, and no visible error messages.

I have restarted MySQL, Flushed the tables, pulled the remote script to test on my dev server, and nothing seems to work.

Running the same query on the table via phpmyadmin on both my dev and remote server returns opposite results, locally it returns zero rows, remotely it returns rows, with the same EXPLAIN result on both(aside from #rows in the table).

Removing the LEAST() functions from the queries, does return data on my dev server.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT id, make, model, LEAST(r24ch10k, r36ch10k, r24ch15k, r36ch15k, r24ch20k, r36ch20k) AS lowest 
    FROM xml 
    WHERE LEAST(r24ch10k, r36ch10k, r24ch15k, r36ch15k, r24ch20k, r36ch20k) != 0.00         
    ORDER BY lowest LIMIT 5
```

**My Local Server Information**:
Server Version: 5.1.51-community
Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
PHP extension: mysqli

**My Remote Server Information**:
Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5
Apache/2.2.16 PHP/5.3.3
MySQL client version: 5.0.51a
PHP extension: mysql

Help in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: If any of the columns are null, do you want the `LEAST()` to return `0`?

Comment: I want to return the lowest value across specified columns that does not equal 0.00

Comment: Let me add, the table is being filled from an XML source, each column represents a node in the XML file, if a node has no value, the value in the table defaults to 0.00.

Comment: GREATEST returns the greatest argument/value that does not equal 0.00 accordingly, and even COALESCE returns a decent set, however I cannot depend on COALESCE to return the lowest value not equal to 0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out with some help at the MySQL forums.

Since what I was looking for was the lowest value, setting the default value to be the lowest possible value is where I err'ed.

I have set the default value for the columns to a high value (9999999999.99), the values added to these columns will never exceed the default value.

So instead of

```
WHERE LEAST(col1, col2, col3) != 0.00
```

I would use

```
WHERE LEAST(col1, col2, col3) != 99999999999.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

> Before MySQL 5.0.13, LEAST() returns
>   NULL only if all arguments are NULL.
>   As of 5.0.13, it returns NULL if any
>   argument is NULL.

Comment: Right, that does help, but shouldn't LEAST() not be returning NULL when the columns within the function set have zero NULL values but rather a defined value of 0.00? - So if I have LEAST(5.00, 0.00, 10.00, 2.00) it would return 2.00 because WHERE its not equal to 0.00

Comment: @Dustin: 0.00 is **not** the same as `NULL`

Comment: @that_horse_without_a_name - I'm not looking for NULL, none of the rows in the columns I am querying have a NULL value, its either 0.00 or greater.